# Symfony 2 : Extending form class : Change label of inherited child

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

Am extending a form class like this :

```
 class RepportDateType extends AbstractType
    {

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder

            ->add('test_date', 'date',array('constraints' => array(
               new NotBlank()),'label'=>'Date','widget'=>'single_text','format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy','input'=>'datetime'))


            ;

        }
}
        class IncidentReportType extends RepportDateType
        {

            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

                $builder

                ->add('end_date', 'date',array('constraints' => array(
                   new NotBlank()),'label'=>'Date de fin','widget'=>'single_text','format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy','input'=>'datetime'))


                ;
            }

            public function getName()
            {
                return 'incident_repport_date';
            }
        }
```

My issue is that i want the parent's form child '**test_date**' label change into **'start date'**
To sum up : how can i change the options of an inherited child

Comment: maybe overrite `test_date` fild in child class?

Comment: @mkjasinski: I think this is not realy the purpose of extending the form, otherwise I'd create my own form :)

Comment: you have right, separate form is better solution :)

Comment: Am sure there is some way to change the label without overriding every thing ;)

Comment: yes, you can use `FormEvents` or many, many others way :)

Comment: What about create a `getDateLabel` method in `RepportDateType` and override it on `IncidentReportType`?